Readin file csv with shared object
I'm trying to create a shared object with Python to read a CSV file to be used by a C application.
I'm having a really hard time doing this.
My code is here:
from cffi import FFI
import csv
import io

ffi = FFI()

ffi.cdef("""
void processCsv(const char[], const char[], const char[]);
void processCsvFile(const char[], const char[], const char[]);
""")

def process_csv(csv_data, selected_columns, row_filter_definitions):
    # Parse the CSV data
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(csv_data.decode('utf-8')))
    headers = csv_reader.fieldnames

    # Parse selected columns
    if selected_columns:
        selected_columns = selected_columns.decode('utf-8').split(',')
    else:
        selected_columns = headers

    # Parse filters
    filters = []
    if row_filter_definitions:
        for line in row_filter_definitions.decode('utf-8').split('\n'):
            if line:
                if '=' in line:
                    header, value = line.split('=')
                    op = '='
                elif '>' in line:
                    header, value = line.split('>')
                    op = '>'
                elif '<' in line:
                    header, value = line.split('<')
                    op = '<'
                filters.append((header, op, value))

    # Apply filters and select columns
    output = io.StringIO()
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=selected_columns)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    
    for row in csv_reader:
        match = all((op == '=' and row[header] == value) or 
                    (op == '>' and row[header] > value) or 
                    (op == '<' and row[header] < value) for header, op, value in filters)
        if match:
            csv_writer.writerow({col: row[col] for col in selected_columns})

    print(output.getvalue(), end='')

def process_csv_file(csv_file_path, selected_columns, row_filter_definitions):
    with open(csv_file_path.decode('utf-8'), 'r') as f:
        process_csv(f.read().encode('utf-8'), selected_columns, row_filter_definitions)

ffi.set_source("_csv_processor",
"""
#include <stdio.h>

void process_csv(const char csv[], const char selectedColumns[], const char rowFilterDefinitions[]);
void process_csv_file(const char csvFilePath[], const char selectedColumns[], const char rowFilterDefinitions[]);

void processCsv(const char csv[], const char selectedColumns[], const char rowFilterDefinitions[]) {
    process_csv(csv, selectedColumns, rowFilterDefinitions);
}

void processCsvFile(const char csvFilePath[], const char selectedColumns[], const char rowFilterDefinitions[]) {
    process_csv_file(csvFilePath, selectedColumns, rowFilterDefinitions);
}
""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffi.compile(verbose=True)

And I'm generating this code with:
python3 csv_processor.py

When I try:
gcc -o programa_c programa_c.c -L. -l_csv_processor -lpython3.10

I receive this error:
/27818bb096b67c55a7a954c23cec29630e6d644e$ gcc -o programa_c programa_c.c -L. -l_csv_processor -lpython3.10
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l_csv_processor: No such file or directory
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The code in C is here:
#include <stdio.h>

void processCsv(const char[], const char[], const char[]);
void processCsvFile(const char[], const char[], const char[]);

int main(){
    const char csv[] = "header1,header2,header3\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9";processCsv(csv, "header1,header3", "header1>1\nheader3<9");
    const char csv_file[] = "data.csv";
processCsvFile(csv_file, "header1,header3", "header1>1\nheader3<9");
    return 0;
}

and I need:

Implement a library that processes CSV files, applying filters and selecting columns as specified. The solution must be able to integrate with the interface defined in C below.


c /**  * Process the CSV data by applying filters and selecting
columns.  *  * @param csv The CSV data to be processed.  * @param
selectedColumns The columns to be selected from the CSV data.  *
@param rowFilterDefinitions The filters to be applied to the CSV data.



@return void  */ void processCsv(const char[], const char[], const char[]);



/**  * Process the CSV file by applying filters and selecting columns.



@param csvFilePath The path to the CSV file to be processed.  * @param selectedColumns The columns to be selected from the CSV data.


@param rowFilterDefinitions The filters to be applied to the CSV data.  *  * @return void  */ void processCsvFile(const char[], const
char[], const char[]);

processCsv

csv: String with CSV data, where each line represents a record and the columns are separated by commas.

Example: "header1,header2,header3\n1,2,3\n4,5,6"


selectedColumns: A string where the names of the columns to be selected are separated by commas.

Example: "header1,header3"


rowFilterDefinitions: A string where each filter is defined on a new line, in the format header(comparador)valor.

Example: "header1>1\nheader2=2\nheader3<6"



processCsvFile

csvFilePath: String with the CSV file path.

Example: "path/to/csv_file.csv"


selectedColumns: A string where the names of the columns to be selected are separated by commas.

Example: "header1,header3"


rowFilterDefinitions: A string where each filter is defined on a new line, in the format header(comparador)valor.

Example: "header1>1\nheader2=2\nheader3<6"




I don't know where I could be going wrong, as I've never worked with this type of application, it's the first time

You cannot link C code to a python script directly like that. It would probably make more sense just to write your code in C. But if you want to mix the two languages you can maybe use the suggestions at How to Call a C Function in Python.

You may also find this useful: Embedding Python in Another Application.
